# How to create a table with multiple indices with Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, create-table

I want to create a new table with (Oracle) SQL with indices for multiple columns, with the indices to be created **at the same time the column is created** (in one statement).
Here (https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-index/oracle-create-index/) I found the statement to create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE members(
    member_id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    first_name VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    dob DATE NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(member_id)
);
```

And in a *second* statement an index for last_name is created:

```
CREATE INDEX members_last_name_i 
ON members(last_name);
```

I would like to know how the `create table` statement has to be modified to have an index for columns "last_name" and "dob" for example. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE members(
    member_id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    first_name VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    dob DATE NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(member_id),
    INDEX members_last_name_i (last_name),
    INDEX date_i (dob)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly, you can not.

`CREATE INDEX` is a separate statement. Only `PRIMARY KEY` constraint *in the background* creates (unique) index which supports it (if such an index doesn't exist yet; if it exists, you can re-use it), but - for the rest of them - you'll have to create them afterwards, one after another.

Comment: Unique index is created only for not deferrable constraint. It's possible to create an index (unique or not depending on the `deferrable` parameter) as a side effect of `unique` constraint and the constraint will be checked for inserts (or may be dropped later), but it's not what should be used to create indexes